# ShowMetroDialogAsyncdoesn't show the dialog when waiting for the task

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, mahapps.metro

I tried to implement a DialogManager like described [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1129#issuecomment-61544345). I'm not using caliburn, so I refactored a bit, and also it's no longer SimpleDialog but CustomDialog, but there weren't big changes.

So now when I click a button that calls `DialogManager.ShowDialog` and wait for the resulting task with `task.Wait()` the application just freezes (as aspected for wait) but without showing the dialog. I tried to debug, but it works alright until the line

```
await Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().First().ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
```

. dialog is a valid `BaseMetroDialog` and i get the right window from the `Application.Cur...` call. It also happens when I'm just calling `ShowMessageAsync`, so the problem seems to be in the connection of the call and the waiting for the task. Is there no way to really block the following execution (forcing the dialog to be modal)?

If you need additional information please comment, I'll extend the question, but right now I don't know what to show besides the code already linked at the beginning.

Comment: Why not use `Application.Current.MainWindow.ShowMetroDialogAsync...`? Is your `Application.MainWindow` not a `MetroWindow`? Note that by design MahApps' dialog is modal and is shown on an overlay of the owning Window.

Comment: mahApps dialog is by design **not** modal, it's async, you just aren't able to click anything else because it lies in front of the window. But anyways, yes you are right I could just use the main window, though I don't think this changes anything becaue atm I get the main window instance back, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention task.Wait(). If you started a task to show the dialog, I'm afraid you can't do that. The GUI is single threaded. You can still await the result, just has to be initiated from the main thread, not a task.

Comment: yeah, you are totally right, should be obvious - dunno why i didnt come to this conclusion :D

Answer (score 0):

This is all the gimmicks I had to do in order to get this to work without having to use async/await:

```
using SysThread = System.Threading;
using WpfThread = System.Windows.Threading;
using SysTasks = System.Threading.Tasks;
using MahCtl = MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahDlg = MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
using Wpf = System.Windows;
.
.
.
private SysThread.CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
.
.
.
    MahCtl.MetroWindow parentMetroWindow = Wpf.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MahCtl.MetroWindow>().First();
    var metroDialogSettings = new MahDlg.MetroDialogSettings();
    metroDialogSettings.OwnerCanCloseWithDialog = true; //does not appear to have any effect
    metroDialogSettings.AnimateHide             = false;
    metroDialogSettings.AnimateShow             = false;
    using( tokenSource = new SysThread.CancellationTokenSource() )
    {
        metroDialogSettings.CancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
        SysTasks.Task<MahDlg.MessageDialogResult> task = MahDlg.DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync( parentMetroWindow, title, message, mahStyle, metroDialogSettings );
        parentMetroWindow.Closing += onMainWindowClosing;
        while( !(task.IsCompleted || task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted) )
            Wpf.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( WpfThread.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action( delegate { } ) );
        parentMetroWindow.Closing -= onMainWindowClosing;
        return task.Result;
    }
.
.
.
private void onMainWindowClosing( object sender, SysCompMod.CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs )
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

The extra handler for the `Closing` event of the main window is necessary in order to handle the situation where the user attempts to close the main window of your application via the task bar, and while a modal dialog box is open, because `OwnerCanCloseWithDialog` does not seem to have any effect, or it was never meant to do what the documentation tricked me into believing that it was perhaps meant to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this was long ago so I can't really check if this works anymore...

Comment: That's okay. It is for the future generations.